# iOS app crahses in adhoc not in debug mode

Tags: ios, crash, adhoc

My app crashes in adhoc Destribution of build through testflight. 
I integrated Flurry too. 
But I am not able to get logs in Flurry. 
And Even no crash logs in devices. 
how to Find the reason/solution of this crash?

Comment: Any fixed step to create crash? or app getting crash in startup?

Comment: app crashes after going in a particular viewcontroller.

Comment: Let me think about solution..

Comment: try this tool [instabug](http://instabug.com)

Comment: you can use crash reports of testflightapp itself. Doesn't it post any useful info?

Comment: Testflightapp provided by apple will release crash reporting in near future. Right now it is not supported by in-build testFlight of apple. Refer below link : 
http://www.imore.com/testflight-ios-8-explained